# IdentityUserClaim instantiation and type casting error in ASP.NET 5 beta6+ app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Problem Description**

I have recently upgraded my ASP.NET 5 application from beta 6 to beta 8. I'm experiencing several problems, however this one flat out stumps me. I am experiencing the following error:

`Using the generic type IdentityUserClaim<TKey>' requires 1 type argument SampleProject.DNX 4.5.1`

**Code**

```
IdentityUserClaim<string> IdentityUserClaimString = await applicationDbContext.UserClaims.SingleAsync(c => c.Id == claimId);

            IdentityUserClaim identityUserClaim = new IdentityUserClaim();
            identityUserClaim.Id = IdentityUserClaimString.Id;
            identityUserClaim.ClaimType = IdentityUserClaimString.ClaimType;
            identityUserClaim.ClaimValue = IdentityUserClaimString.ClaimValue;
            identityUserClaim.UserId = IdentityUserClaimString.UserId;
            return (identityUserClaim);
```

**Attempts**

I tried making a generic class, but as a rule I try not to rewrite base packages or even extend ones given to us.

As I understand the error, it wants me to change `IdentitUserClaim` to something like `IdentityUserClaim<int>` for example. However, this is not how I understood this library or used it in ASP.NET5 up to beta6. I have been using it generically.

So my question is, is there any way I can fix this without having to radically rewriting my code or am I going to have to rewrite my custom Identity claims because there is some change or enforcement of code rules I was unaware of in beta6+ package `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`?

Please just take it on my word that I have a usecase for making custom claims. Thank you for your time, patience, and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a non-generic `IdentityUserClaim` class which used `string` as type param for `TKey`:

```
public class IdentityUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string> { }
```

This class (and several others), however, [were removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/commit/19d56be977390e6abcdb7d789d9c18e7ce1de89a) in beta7. You could add the class again to your own code-base if you'd like, or just use `IdentityUserClaim<string>`.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, I can then invoke IdentityUserClaim<string> and it will be equivalent to my original case. If so I have learned more about the code base and will refactor to keep dependencies and custom code to a minimum. Right?

Comment: That's correct @hlyates. `new IdentityUserClaim<string>()` will result in the same.